# Can I define the size of a C element in bits?

Tags: c

In the following example, can I define the size of a C element in bits?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
    false = 0,
    true = ~0
} bool;

int main(void) {
    bool x;
    printf("%d", sizeof x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know the size, or to make it be a desired size?

Comment: @ugoren I don't need to know how to get the size; it is being printed.

Comment: Do you perhaps want a [bit field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field)?

Comment: Clang, as an extension for C++ interop with ObjC, has the ability to have a fixed underlying type for an enum, that's about as close as you can get to my knowledge.

Comment: An enum is int in C. There is no way around that, as far as I know. So your enum will have the same size as an int.

Comment: @BuellaGábor I feared as much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enum` is of int size. All i need to do is make the implicit cast explicit.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
    true = ~(int)0,
    false = (int)0
} bool;

int main(void) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In general, no. The minimum addressable unit is a byte, not a bit.

You can do funny things with [bitfields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field), such as:

```
struct {
    unsigned a : 31;
    unsigned b : 1;
};
```

That struct will **likely have** a `sizeof == 4`, `a` will use 31 bits of space, and `b` will use 1 bit of space.

Comment: +1.  I notice (and appreciate) you use _likely_.  It does depend on things like ***[THIS](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/)***.

Comment: From what I recall with working on embedded systems (it's been a while), compilers render single bit bitfields as efficiently as you'd imagine, but multi-bit fields are a crap-shoot in terms of efficiency.  Safer to just use masks.